# Inserting multidimensional array as row in R

Tags: r, arrays, json, dataframe

I have two dataframes with this structure:

The first one:

```
ID, User, name, lastname
1, jjuan, Juan, Perez
2, ccort, Mario, Linares
3, ractt, Ana, Contreras
```

The second one:

```
user, category, count, fraction
jjuan,  Fruits, 681, 0.21
jjuan, Vegetables, 247,0.08
jjuan, chicken, 2262, 0.71
ccort,  Fruits, 681, 0.21
ccort, Vegetables, 247,0.08
ccort, chicken, 2262, 0.71
ractt,  Fruits, 681, 0.21
ractt, Vegetables, 247,0.08
ractt, chicken, 2262, 0.71
```

This dataset is repeated for every user of the first one

I want to insert the second one in the first dataset as a list for every user and create a json with the all information:

```
{
  "": " #ElSalvador ",
  "fecha": " 2021-12-09 11:55:14 ",
  "requestid": " 618d48fe21d88a05e4b4b52b ",
  "Users": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "User": "jjuan",
      "name": "Juan",
      "lastname": "Perez",
      "values": [
        {
          "category": "Fruits",
          "count": 681,
          "fraction": 0.21
        },
        {
          "category": "Vegetables",
          "count": 247,
          "fraction": 0.08
        },
        {
          "category": "chicken",
          "count": 2262,
          "fraction": 0.71
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "User": "ccort",
      "name": "Mario",
      "lastname": "Linares",
      "values": [
        {
          "category": "Fruits",
          "count": 681,
          "fraction": 0.21
        },
        {
          "category": "Vegetables",
          "count": 247,
          "fraction": 0.08
        },
        {
          "category": "chicken",
          "count": 2262,
          "fraction": 0.71
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "User": "ractt",
      "name": "Ana",
      "lastname": "Contreras",
      "values": [
        {
          "category": "Fruits",
          "count": 681,
          "fraction": 0.21
        },
        {
          "category": "Vegetables",
          "count": 247,
          "fraction": 0.08
        },
        {
          "category": "chicken",
          "count": 2262,
          "fraction": 0.71
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The idea is to have all the information of the second dataset as a multidimentional array.

The second idea is, first calculate the values and insert them for every user as a multidimentional

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you're looking for a full outer join `df3 <- merge(x = df_1, y = df_2, all = TRUE)`, which assumes that at least row order (as opposed to a shared column) is the same for `ccort` and others in df_1 & df_2. Then pull you json from df3, by row.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i made some changes to the original questions since I realize that it was not clear and I did not give the all structure lf the dataset 2.

Comment: I found a solution, it was quite easy. You just have to send a list dataset1$cat <-list(dataset2)

Comment: And it is acceptable form to answer one's own question and then accept the answer. Answered questions are generally first searched as they indicate programming solutions.  In your answer, with short example data, also show the pulling into json/tensor...the full round trip.